# What is Bing's search engine URL for queries?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine, bing

So while editing my search engines on Chrome, I accidentally deleted Bing, and now i want to make it my default browser. i have tried to use the 'Make bing your homepage' application by microsoft, however it is not allowing me to install it as it says "It is already installed", I understand why it says that because i have installed it in the past but i deleted the configurations. So when i try to add a new search engine this comes up:
[image: I have cropped this image]

And here is a picture of what Google's default settings look like:
[image]

Comment: The answers here worked well for years. Now they fail more often than they succeed. The error is something like "It's not you, it's us."

Answer (score 3):

Open Setting in Chrome, then search ***Manage search engines*** then click on add new
Enter the following configuration

> Search Engine: Bing
>
> Keyword: bing.com
>
> URL with %s in place of query: https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s

[image]

Now Click on Make default

[image]

---

now if enter anything in the address bar and hit enter it will search on Bing

Answer (score 0):

this is what i'm getting on my chrome:

search engine: `Bing`,

keyword: `bing.com`

url with %s `https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s`

also if you try on your browser this link with a keyword instead of %s var it will redirect to bing with the query made.

there are more query params you can get with bing

**For more official read about bing web search query parameters:**

[Web Search API v7 reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v7-reference)

[Web Search API v5 reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v5-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Search engine: **Bing**

Keyword: **Bing** *(but any word will work here, as long as you don't leave it empty)*

URL with %s in place of query: **https://bing.com/search?q=%search%**

*In this last field you can also write anything you want, as long as it's the Bing URL and as long as the word "search" is the same before the question mark and between the two percentage signs. But you could write any word instead of the actual word "search."*

Comment: You can't replace the "search" before the question mark with arbitrary words. It must be "search".

Answer (score 0):

Only this query worked in my case

```
https://www.bing.com/?q=%s
```

Other variants with the word "search" works, but returns weird queries in the search bar.

After editing may require to restart your browser.